# How to parse numbers from a .m file to a empty 3D Matrix in another .m file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a file named my_random_numbers.m which has a list of random numbers that were generated. In a separate .m file I have a 3D Matrix `RAND_matrix = zeros(rows,cols,depth);` initialized to all zeros. Now I need to populate this empty 3D Matrix using the list of numbers.
Example of how the number looks like

```
128,  0,  6,  0,  0, 40,  0,  1,224,  0,  8,128,  0,102,  0,
  2,168,  0, 31,224,  0,128,128,  6,  6,  0, 40, 40,  1,225,224,
  8,136,128,102,102,  2,170,168, 31,255,224,128,  0,134,  0,  6,
 40,  0, 41,224,  1,232,128,  8,230,  0,100,168,  2,183,224, 31,
 96,128,134,134,  6, 46, 40, 41,201,225,233,104,136,238,230,100,
```

Please help me understand how I can do this as I have been searching online for quite a bit but dont understand how to do this. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? `csvread`?

Comment: The numbers shown do not form a rectangular matrix. Is that how your file really is, or is that a typo?

Comment: @JamesTursa these are just a small snippit sample of the numbers i gave here for example just to show what the numbers look like.

Comment: @SMRAFI but its not square, therefore isn't a matrix.

Comment: Also trying to parse numbers from a .m file would be a weird thing to do. Do you actually just have a big vector created in one script that you want to [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to a 3D matrix in another script?

Comment: Please specify how you want to place a 1D list of numbers in the 3D matrix. What is desired relation between the position in the 1D list and the position in the 3D matrix?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB is capable of saving the workspace produced by a script as a .mat file. This can then be accessed by any other script that has the same working folder as the one where the .mat file is saved.

For example if your first MATLAB script file is:

```
testMat = magic(10);
check = "Check string";
other = 180;
save('dotMatFileName');
```

and your second MATLAB script file is:

```
load('dotMatFileName');
disp(testMat);
```

Then your second MATLAB script will display the 10 large magic square generated in the first MATLAB script. Your second MATLAB script will also import the `check` and `other` variables from the first MATLAB script.

The `save()` function can also save specific variables. For example, if you change the first MATLAB script to say,

```
testMat = magic(10);
check = "Check string";
other = 180;
save('dotMatFileName', "testMat");
```

Then the script will only save a .mat file containing the `testMat` magic square variable as `dotMatFileName.mat` in the working folder of the first MATLAB script.